# Quran ebook for kindle

Tags: kindle

I have been trying to find Quran ebook for my Kindle, but haven't found anything notable yet. Are there any good ebooks out there ? My preference is for Arabic text with tashkil, i.e. diacritics. Here is an example of the Arabic text with diacritics :

[image: Simple arabic text with diacritics]

With for example a mobi file, you can change spacing, font style, and font size. I appreciate any recommendations.

**Edit**

Here is an example of two screenshots superimposed from two ebooks I have found so far (apparently I need 10+ rep to post more than two links)

[image: comparison shots]

The problem for the upper image is that the margin to the left is completely unnecessary, while on the right hand side and bottom, the margin is too great. At the bottom it should end right where the Arabic numeral appears. The only margin setting which allows to keep at maximum is simply not good enough for this file.

The best ebook format I have come upon is the one depicted at the bottom. Here, there is less text per page which makes the text more readable. And finally the margins are to the bare minimum (except at the bottom). I have linked to the website in the comments where I found these ebooks (as I need 10 reputation to be able to post three or more links).

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a site for book recommendations; it's for technical difficulties and issues related to producing and consuming ebooks.

Comment: I tried asking at Islam beta, but got a similar response there. The thing is that it is difficult finding an ebook for the Quran. Not sure where else I can try my luck. Of the ebooks I have managed to find, there is no possibility to fiddle with anything. But if what you state is true, then yes this question is off-topic.

Comment: The link I mentioned in the post above : https://sites.google.com/site/kindlequran/download

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of the content, flowable text is out of the question and thus all formats which depend on HTML and CSS in some form or another shouldn't be used.

The best choice for this use-case would be to use PDF, this would ensure the content is 'fixed'. The other limitation is that the content is not presentable using a single font, thus images have to be used; this is why fixed-layout ebook formats are not usable in this case as well.

I don't know of other ways of obtaining such a PDF file besides what you have already mentioned, so I decided to have a go at it myself with LaTeX.

Here's what I did:

1) Generate high-resolution PNG files of each page. You can use Quran.com's image generator found [here](https://github.com/quran/quran.com-images). If you're on a Windows machine, you can use my fork found [here](https://github.com/khalid-hussain/quran.com-images).

2) Prepare a LaTeX document with settings specific to the geometry of your Kindle device.

3) Place each page image on a single PDF page and add page numbers and related footers/headers as you see fit.

I've tried creating a sample PDF with the first four pages, you can check the output in the comments (I don't have 10 reputation points yet).

Comment: You can check my sample PDF [here](https://github.com/khalid-hussain/KindleMushaf/blob/master/kindle_mushaf.pdf).

Comment: Give me a few days! This looks awesome.